# Workplace stung with Sr.Director relatives friends

Tags: nepotism

I am in an IT(Information technology) sector Sr.Director placed his close relatives and friends in department, and all form a informal hierarchy , and past 6 months ago , I started questioning the projects they receive and giving suggesting to leadership , which the Sr.Director did not like and as part of organization restructure , me being an employee , he let me go to a sub vendor . I still work in the same department but now not as a employee but contractor . I have patiently seen his relatives and school friends getting promotions and huge bonuses , and for me asking questions on the process was literally fired. 
I was thinking from long time to report this anonymously to HR , will HR take any action on the Sr.Director . I dont want ohters to face the same problems and stress i went through if nobody atleast brings to the attention on HR .

Please let me know how to complain to HR , as i am now a contractor . will writing an anonymous email in a huge orgination explaining them about all of this relative and school friends who are causing a toxic environment to work . Please help . I think i should atleast go ahead and send out emails to HR and CEO.

Comment: Voting to close as off topic - "Questions should get answers explaining why and how to make a decision, not advice on what to do"

Comment: Email won't be anonymous, they'll trace you by your spelling pretty quickly.

Comment: Ryan  , one of my friends/colleague had almost similar issues. What he did was , he found a new job and on the last day sent a note to HR detailing every complaint he had with concrete examples and dates. In less than 6 months later , the director and his favourite subordinates were let go . You don't stand a chance of winning but maybe you can write an email on your last day when you have found a new job and i would say non anonymously.

Comment: How do you see any of this working out well for you?

Answer (score 2):

Likely nothing good would come from this. You complained once as an employee and got fired.  You think complaining again as contractor will go better?  As contractor you are just paid to do your job.  If you do send an anonymous email then you need to work on your writing.  Capitalize i and don't put a space before .

Comment: Honestly I wonder in these types of questions if it is not really the OP's fault for being in a bad situation? The reason being is that spelling and grammar are so bad that it's hard for even us to understand much less anyone at this company. Could be after 10 of these emails that they simply given up on trying to help them?

Comment: @Dan It is the OP's problem for handing it poorly.  Sounds like he *questioned* for a while and I suspect he was given some pretty direct clues to dial it back.

Answer (score 0):

The sole owner of a company can do whatever he or she likes (within the laws). It may be unwise to do so, but legal.

Any employee of a company, including a senior director who is not the sole owner, is supposed to do what is best for the company. If he or she acts against the interests of the company, he or she should be reprimanded up to being fired. The question is: Is that going to happen?

If he or she is high up enough, then it isn't going to happen due to anything that HR does. It's going to happen if his boss or the company owner figures out that the senior director is costing the company money, and is not happy about that. It's also very much a matter of the country where you are living and the company culture. If that kind of thing is common (and his boss or the company owner does the same thing), then nothing is going to happen.

And you have one problem: Hiring relatives or school friends is Ok if these relatives and school friends are doing a good job. You'd need some evidence that the people he or she hired are actually not doing a good job. The bonuses that you told us about must come from some budget. Is there another group of people that can't get any bonus, no matter how good they are, because the bonuses get paid to friends and relatives? Are their salaries too high for the jobs they do? Without any evidence about that, you will have a hard time.

Answer (score 0):

A contractor's complaints will carry even less weight than an employee, since the company has less contractual tie to you. So consider your options:

**HR are genuinely unaware of what's going on** - if the nepotism is as blatant as you say, this gives little hope that HR is competent to do anything about it.

**HR turn a blind eye out of fear of reprisals** - you got fired for complaining, they are very likely aware that the same thing will happen to them if they pursue a complaint against the wrong person, or one of his allies.

**HR are in on the scheme** - in which case a complaint is hopeless.

You mentioned stress - getting the result you want will be a long, stressful and potentially risky process (expect to get fired again) with no guaranteed result; and even then, what will you gain from it except a sense of justice? Polish your CV and when a good opportunity comes along, leave this toxic place to crash and burn, as it surely will.